# Access Product2 lookup from OrderItem object

Tags: orderitem

I'm trying to access fields of the Product2 parent from the OrderItem and running into a strange error, *"No such column 'Product2Id' on entity 'OrderItem'"*. The following string of code works when run from Execute Anonymous, but does not compile when written within an Apex Class (see screenshot below):

```
List<OrderItem> oiList = [SELECT Id, Product2Id, Product2.Name FROM OrderItem];

    for(OrderItem oi : oiList){
        System.debug(oi.Product2.Name);
```

The Product2 lookup field clearly exists and is [documented](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_orderitem.htm), but I can't access it in my Apex code. On the other hand, a SOQL query of the Order with OrderItems works fine (see second screenshot). Kindly assist.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The Product2Id field and its relationship were introduced in a later API version than your class is set to (38.0). Try changing it to 57.0, and it should deploy.

Comment: Worked like a charm, thank you.

Comment: @TonyKirumba Yeah, no problem. Glad I could help!